# Type mismatch error : Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to write a scala program to find prime numbers and have written the code below:

```
object primenumber {
  import scala.collection.mutable
  import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
  def primenumber_func(raw_arr: Array[Int]){
      var raw_arbuf = raw_arr.toBuffer
      var del_arr = new ArrayBuffer[Int]() 
      for(ctx <- 2 to (raw_arbuf.max-1)){
           del_arr = raw_arbuf.filter(_%ctx == 0)
           raw_arbuf = raw_arbuf diff del_arr
   }
   println(raw_arbuf)
   }
  }
```

and facing the below error:

```
<console>:18: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[Int]
 required: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int]
```

Any suggestion on what i am doing wrong is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Another possibility: `var raw_arbuf = raw_arr.to[ArrayBuffer]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write

```
var del_arr: mutable.Buffer[Int] = new ArrayBuffer[Int]()
```

instead of just

```
var del_arr = new ArrayBuffer[Int]()
```

Otherwise Scala compiler infers type of `del_arr` to be implementation type `ArrayBuffer[Int]` rather than trait type `Buffer[Int]`, and `filter` returns `Buffer[Int]`, so you can't re-assign `del_arr`.

By the way, `primenumber_func((1 to 100).toArray)` produces `ArrayBuffer(1)`. Is that desirable behavior?

Comment: Thanks Dmytro, Used .filter(_!=ctx) as well to give only prime numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I would say to better avoid using mutable state and try solving this problem with higher order functions. For example., here is a one liner that will do this for you!

```
def isPrime(num: Int): Boolean = (2 to num) forall (x => num % x != 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! Used the same for something else!

Comment: I believe Sieve of Eratosthenes is slightly more efficient if you need to find all primes in a list of `Int`s.